# Proxy pass the thousands of domain names to internal ips with any ports sent

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having issues in proxy passing the domain name to internal ip with any ports requested

**Architecture of system**

```
   s1.wd.com         s2.wd.com
        |               |
        -----------------
                |
                |
          Central-Server (AWS EC2)
          (160.120.1.1)
                |
        -----------------
        |               |
      IoT1             IoT2
   (10.0.0.11)      (10.0.0.12)

s1.wd.com -> Central Server -> 10.0.0.11

s1.wd.com:3000 -> Central Server -> 10.0.0.11:3000

s1.wd.com:3001 -> Central Server -> 10.0.0.11:3001

s1.wd.com:5001 -> Central Server -> 10.0.0.11:5001

s1.wd.com:6001 -> Central Server -> 10.0.0.11:6001
```

- We can have 1000's of domains like s1.wd.com, s2.wd.com, s..n.wd.com server which point to our main "Central Server" running with IP 160.120.1.1
- We have to reverse proxy (proxy pass) and forward all the requests from the "Central Server" to the 1000's of IoT devices along with the PORTS that are being sent as shown above

Currently I am trying to achieve with Nginx but having no luck.

**/etc/nginx/domains_with_ip.conf**

```
s1.wd.com 10.0.0.11;
www.s1.wd.com 10.0.0.11;
s2.wd.com 10.0.0.12;
www.s2.wd.com 10.0.0.12;
s3.wd.com 10.0.0.13;
www.s3.wd.com 10.0.0.13;
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/wireguard.wd.com**

We are referring the domain names with ip_address from the above **domains_with_ip.conf** file

```
map $http_host $backend {
    include /etc/nginx/domains_with_ip.conf;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    set $domains /etc/nginx/domains.conf;

    server_name $domains;
    client_max_body_size 10000M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$backend:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # Proxy redirect settings
        proxy_redirect off;

        # HTTP version settings
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        # Response buffering from proxied server default 1024m
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        # Proxy cache bypass define conditions under the response will not be taken from cache
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Tried by best with IPTables too but no luck. Any solutions or redirect to any resources will be really helpful.